# How can we write a text file from variable using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, variables, text

I am working on NLP project and have extracted the text from pdf using PyPDF2. Further, I removed the blank lines. Now, my output is being shown on the console but I want to populate the text file with the same data which is stored in my variable (file).

Below is the code which is removing the blank lines from a text file.

```
for line in open('resume1.txt'):
  line = line.rstrip()
  if line != '':
    file=line
    print(file)
```

**Output on Console:**
Eclipse,
Visual Studio 2012,
Arduino IDE,
Java
,
HTML,
CSS
2013
Excel
.

Now, I want the same data in my (resume1.txt) text file. I have used three methods but all these methods print a single dot in my resume1.txt file. If I see at the end of the text file then there is a dot which is being printed.

**Method 1:**

```
with open("resume1.txt", "w") as out_file:
    out_file.write(file)
```

**Method 2:**

```
print(file,  file=open("resume1.txt", 'w'))
```

**Method 3:**

```
pathlib.Path('resume1.txt').write_text(file)
```

Could you please be kind to assist me in populating the text file. Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: If you're writing this _after_ the loop, then `file` will contain the _last_ non-empty line, which happens to be the full stop/dot.

Comment: Hi, should I be writing this inside the loop.

Comment: @Yousaf yes write inside loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that you are writing to the same file losing the old data, I don't know if you want to do that. Other than that, every time you write using those methods, you are overwriting the data you previously wrote to the output file. So, if you want to use these methods, you must write just 1 time (write all the data).

### SOLUTIONS

#### Using method 1:

```
to_file = []

for line in open('resume1.txt'):
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line != '':
        file = line
        print(file)
        to_file.append(file)

to_save = '\n'.join(to_file)

with open("resume1.txt", "w") as out_file:
    out_file.write(to_save)
```

#### Using method 2:

```
to_file = []

for line in open('resume1.txt'):
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line != '':
        file = line
        print(file)
        to_file.append(file)

to_save = '\n'.join(to_file)

print(to_save, file=open("resume1.txt", 'w'))
```

#### Using method 3:

```
import pathlib

to_file = []

for line in open('resume1.txt'):
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line != '':
        file = line
        print(file)
        to_file.append(file)

to_save = '\n'.join(to_file)

pathlib.Path('resume1.txt').write_text(to_save)
```

In these 3 methods, I have used `to_save = '\n'.join(to_file)` because I'm assuming you want to separate each line of other with an EOL, but if I'm wrong, you can just use `''.join(to_file)` if you want not space, or `' '.join(to_file)` if you want all the lines in a single one.

#### Other method

You can do this by using other file, let's say 'output.txt'.

```
out_file = open('output.txt', 'w')

for line in open('resume1.txt'):
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line != '':
        file = line
        print(file)
        out_file.write(file)
        out_file.write('\n') # EOL

out_file.close()
```

Also, you can do this (I prefer this):

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in open('resume1.txt'):
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line != '':
            file = line
            print(file)
            out_file.write(file)
            out_file.write('\n') # EOL
```

Comment: It's working fine now. Thank you so much. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Yousaf you're welcome. If this helped, I would appreciate it if you mark this answer as the solution. If this is not the solution, please provide more information about what you need.

Answer (score 0):

First post on stack, so excuse the format

```
new_line = ""

for line in open('resume1.txt', "r"):
    for char in line:
        if char != " ":
            new_line += char
print(new_line)



with open('resume1.txt', "w") as f:
    f.write(new_line)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. It is only removing spaces in between the words. However, I want to remove blank lines...

e.g

Hello

World

Output should be: 

Hello
World